# Flutter Stripe latest version not showing google pay button with Flutter Stripe Packages

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I have enabled Google and Apple in Stripe Account and when I show Bottom Sheet Google Pay Button not visisble

Here is my initPaymentSheet method
my package is **flutter_stripe: ^9.1.0**

```
 paymentIntentData = await createPaymentIntent(value, 'GBP');

      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
              paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
              applePay: PaymentSheetApplePay(merchantCountryCode:'UK'),
              googlePay: PaymentSheetGooglePay(
                  merchantCountryCode: 'UK',
                  testEnv: true,
                  currencyCode: "gbp"),
              style: ThemeMode.light,
              merchantDisplayName: 'off'
          ))
          .then((value) {}
      );
```

```
 await Stripe.instance
          .presentPaymentSheet(
          options: PaymentSheetPresentOptions()
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why Google Pay isn't showing up like are you testing on a physical device or emulator? Are you testing from a supported region? and so on..

Looking at the code you've provided, it seems like you're setting the wrong `merchantCountryCode`. It should be `merchantCountryCode: 'GB'` I think.

Comment: Now my region is not supported (Pakistan). before this its work perfetly 3 month ago, after flutter packages and version  upgradting not working even i down grade alos but not showing google pay button, I test it on both Physical and Emulator.

Comment: GB alos i tried this "GB" but stil not working